# Why I should believe that the derivative of the determinant is the trace

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, trace

Using a Taylor expansion, it is not hard to show that the derivative of the determinant function at the identity is the trace:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ \det(I + tA) - \det(I) }{ t } = \operatorname{tr}(A).
$$
The determinant of a matrix may be viewed as the change in area of regions in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  A square of area $1$ will be converted to a shape of area $\det(A)$.  This change in area is the product of the eigenvalues, as opposed to the sum.  What is a good intuitive way of seeing that the derivative would be the trace?

Comment: I think the first term is $det(I+tA)$, no?

Comment: $$\prod^n_{k=1}(1-t\lambda_k)=1-t\sum^n_{k=1}\lambda_k+O(t^2)$$ may be formal, but it's probably intuitive enough for many.

Comment: "Suppose small changes are made in the edges of a parallelepiped. Then the main contribution to the change in volume of the parallelepiped is due to the change of each edge in its own direction, changes in the direction of the other edges making only a second-order contribution to the change in volume." (V. I. Arnold, Ordinary Differential Equations)

Also take a look at this thread: https://mathoverflow.net/a/46455/107094

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Comment: @leonbloy Fixed.

Comment: @Hyperplane What does he mean by "other edges".  Thanks for the thread as well.  That was quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take $N$ vectors with coordinates $(1, 0, 0...)^T, (0, 1, 0, ...)^T, ... (0, 0,..., 1)^T$.

$N$ vectors determine a parallelepiped, to find a volume of this parallelepiped we compose a matrix of components of these vectors and calculate it's determinant. In our case the matrix is identity matrix, the parallelepiped is a unit cube, it's volume is 1, $\det(I)$ is 1.

We can consider matrix $I+tA$ also as coordinates of $N$ vectors. $\det(I+tA)$ is a volume of a parallelepiped formed by these vectors.

Each of these $N$ vectors is close to the corresponding unit vector, and the whole parallelepiped is just a slightly distorted unit cube.

See what happens. There was a vector $(1, 0, 0....)^T$, now we have a slightly different vector $(1+a_1*t, a_2*t, ....)$. When we changed the first coordinate the volume of parallelepiped increased approximately by $1*a_1*t$: this is the "area of a square side * thickness of the layer". But when we change some other coordinates the affects only the regions along the edges of the cube. The change of parallelepiped's volume would be $O(t^2)$ and can be ignored.

It's easy to visualise this in 3-D case, and not much changes in case of higher dimensions.

So, the total change of volume would be $t*(a_1+a_2+...) + o(t)$.

So: $d(\det(I + tA))/dt = d(V)/dt = Tr(A)$

Update: I guess V.I.Arnold (link suggested in comments) explained the same, but better...

Comment: Actually, I think your explanation is the better one.

Answer (score 2):

The identity $\det\exp X =\exp\text{tr}X$ is obviously valid for diagonal $X$, and this generalises to diagonalisable matrices (since $X\to OXO^T$ with orthogonal $O$ changes neither determinants not traces) and from there to all square matrices (because the diagonalisable matrices are dense). The choice $X=\ln (I-tA)$ for small $t$ gives $$\det (I-tA)=\exp\text{tr}\ln (I-tA)\approx\exp(-t\text{tr}A)\approx 1-t\text{tr}A=\det I-t\text{tr}A.$$

Answer (score 1):

Off diagonal elements correspond to transvections which does not change the volume while a (positive) diagonal element changes the volume with precisely that factor. Write $E_{ij}$ for the matrix with 1 in the $i,j$-th place, all other being zero. By what we have just said, the change in volume when applying the matrix $I+a_{ij} E_{ij}$ is $1$ if $i\neq j$ and $1+a_{ii}$ if $i=j$.

To first order in $t$ we may decompose $I+tA$ as:
$$ 
 I+ tA = \prod_{i,j} (I+ t \; a_{ij} E_{ij}) + O(t^2)
$$

On the other hand, successively applying each of the elementary operations indicated in the product we get the volume transformation:
$$ \prod_{i,j} (1 + t \; a_{ij} \delta_{i,j}) = \prod_{i} (1+ t a_{ii}) = 
1+ t \sum_i a_{ii} +O(t^2) = 1 + t \; {\rm tr} A + O(t^2)
$$
(The above argument is similar to the one used to show geometrically, that the determinant indeed gives the volume transformation of a linear map).